# ckan integration with angular

Tags: angular, jinja2, angular2-template, ckan

I am trying to add some front end pages in Angular to the my ckan extension.
But with the Jinja templating in ckan I am finding it really hard to achieve this.
I need to know if this is possible / supported (with any version of angular).

**If this is supported, can someone please share any example where this is integrated.**
If not what are my options of achieving this in ckan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was a long time ago, and it's not very pleasant, but it is possible, e.g.:
https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-smartlane/blob/master/ckanext/smartlane/templates/package/analyses.html
https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-smartlane/tree/master/ckanext/smartlane/fanstatic/app

Key things to watch out for are getting the JS loaded properly:
https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-smartlane/blob/master/ckanext/smartlane/fanstatic/resource.config#L2

And stopping Jinja templating from reading the Angular templating with the {% raw %} tag:
https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-smartlane/blob/5e5c51bb355061789069f329ff33b4a8e8844c0e/ckanext/smartlane/templates/package/analyses.html#L13

That repository is a bit hard to navigate; you probably want to only look at the state at revision 5e5c51bb355061789069f329ff33b4a8e8844c0e, i.e. https://github.com/smartlane/ckanext-smartlane/tree/5e5c51bb355061789069f329ff33b4a8e8844c0e/ckanext/smartlane

Hope that helps!

Comment: So the answer is "don't do it"